# Using the distributive law in propositional calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

So I was given this proof in class:

~p ^ q = (~ p v q) ^ ~(~q ^ p)

= (~ p v q) ^ (q v ~p)                  by double negative law.

= ~p ^ (q ^ ~p) v ( q ^ ( q ^ ~p))      by distributive law.

...etc...

Note: The prof said take ( q v ~p) to be r

Can someone explain how he went from the 2nd to 3rd step by the distributive law?

Comment: Your "by double negative law" is probably wrong. $$\neg(A\vee B) = \neg A \wedge \neg B$$

Comment: @peterwhy edited, had the wrong sign.

Comment: Your "by double negative law" is still probably wrong.
$$\neg(A\wedge B) = \neg A \vee \neg B$$

Answer (score 1):

The distributive law says that
$$A \land (B \lor C) \equiv (A \land B) \lor (A \land C).$$
What you have so far is
$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (q \lor \neg p).$$
Now let us write $r$ as shorthand for $(q \lor \neg p)$, so we can write it as
$$(\neg p \lor q) \land r.$$
Using distributivity, this means
$$(\neg p \lor q) \land r \equiv (r \land \neg p) \lor (r \land q),$$
and putting $(q \lor \neg p)$ back in again instead of $r$, we get
$$(\neg p \lor q) \land (q \lor \neg p) \equiv ((q \lor \neg p) \land \neg p) \lor ((q \lor \neg p) \land q).$$